# Asking the user to enter in numbers, getting min/max/and average

Tags: input, sum, max, min

Hi guys I'm have a real hard time for some reason trying to get this code worked out. My guide lines are:

- Create a new Scanner object and save it into a variable name of your choice
- Declare an integer variable for the current user’s input and initialize it to something that is NOT 0 (we will call it intInput in these instructions – the name is arbitrary, though)
- Create a while loop, with the condition being that intInput is not equal to 0
- Inside of this loop, call the nextInt() method of your Scanner object and store the value into intInput

I'm not getting any errors but its not working the way I thought it would.

and here is my code:

```java
 import java.util.Scanner;

// class name matches the file name
     public class Lab5
     {
  // we must have a main method to run the program
  `enter code here`public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

      int userInput = 1;
      int minVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      int maxVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      double average = 0;
      int holdNum = 0;
      double numSum = 0;

      System.out.print ("Please enter numbers and to finish the program your last number should be 0: ");
      numSum += userInput;
      holdNum++;

      while (userInput != 0)
      {
          userInput = scan.nextInt();
      }

      if (maxVal > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      {
          maxVal = userInput;
      }
      if (minVal < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
      {
          minVal = userInput;
      }
       average = ( numSum ) / ( holdNum );

       System.out.println( "Average = " + average );
       System.out.println( "Max = " + maxVal );
       System.out.println( "Minimum = " + minVal );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the user input in the sum and incrementing the number of user inputs only when the input is less than the minimum. I would guess you'll want to do it for all inputs instead.

Comment: Sorry about that i fell asleep after I posted. Thanks for the info . I moved both the sum and the incrementing up to the front of the code right under my print telling the user what to do. I'm still not getting the proper numbers. I enter in 1,2,3,4,0 separately. My average it says in 1.0 (should be 2), Max comes out to 2147483647, and min says -2147483648. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: You use Integer.MIN_VALUE as the initial minimum value. No integer is less than that, so the initial value is never changed. The same thing happens with the initial maximum value: no integer is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE. As for the average, could you update the code in the question? As it stands it prints the average on every run of the loop.

Comment: Sorry had a class that doesn't allow laptops out. Now I have a free hr to work on this.

Comment: notice that all of the if statements and other logic is outside of the loop... the loop will gobble up all the numbers that you give to it, ignoring every single one of them

Comment: Thanks I think I got it now. I got to change a few things up first but I think it will work now.